# Mysql query, populate a value based on other

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

```
meta_id | post_id  |         meta_key   |      meta_value
----------------------------------------------------------
19368   |    5716  | _wpbdp[fields][8]  |
19369   |    5716  | _wpbdp[fields][9]  |    124_ico.jpg    
19370   |    5716  | _wpbdp[fields][10] |
```

This is my mysql table. I want that if for a postid the metakey `_wpbdp[fields][9]` has some value assigned(124_ico.jpg) in this case, then _wpbdp[fields][10] metavalue is updated to 124_img.jpg

Any help with the query would be great.

Comment: thanks for the edits guys.. and yes i want it for WP, but i'm looking to run the query directly via phpmyadmin

Comment: What if you have a `_wpbdp[fields][11]`?

Comment: yes i do but i think it should be something like UPDATE metavalue = (our desired value) where meta_key="_wpbdp[fields][10] " so dont think _wpbdp[fields][11] will cause a problem, isnt it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the '_wpbdp[fields][10]' rows of a given post_id to have the same meta_value as a row for the same post_id where the meta_value is filled in then you can use the following:

```
update tbl t join (select post_id, meta_value
                     from tbl
                    where meta_value is not null) x on t.post_id = x.post_id
   set t.meta_value = replace(x.meta_value, '_ico', '_img')
 where t.meta_key = '_wpbdp[fields][10]'
```

See fiddle at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6656ae/1/0

Comment: thanx for a start.. but not all rows, only the one where metakey =_wpbdp[fields][10]

Comment: @user1994082 then you can just add that to the where clause. I updated my answer.

Comment: FIxed it!!!                                                             update tbl t join (select post_id, meta_value
                         from tbl
                        where meta_value is not null) x on t.post_id = x.post_id
       set t.meta_value = REPLACE(x.meta_value,'_ico','_img')
     where t.meta_key = '_wpbdp[fields][10]'

Comment: @user1994082 I thought that was just a typo in your question, I'll update the answer. Glad it's working anyway

Comment: Sorry Brian, dont have the repo to upvote :) Here is the solution fiddle :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0493bd/1/0

Comment: @user1994082 It's a bit late, but "Welcome at SO!" You'll get the needed reputation sooner or later. You can upvote then - and this would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @var:= meta_value FROM t WHERE meta_value IS NOT NULL;
SELECT @no:= REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(meta_key,']',-2),'[',''),']','')+1 FROM t
WHERE meta_value IS NOT NULL;
UPDATE t 
SET meta_value =  @var 
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(meta_key,']',-2),'[',''),']','')=
@no
ORDER BY meta_id
```